# Magento 2 - CSS not loading after module install

Tags: magento2, module, css, command-line

My css isn't loading after I installed and enabled a `module` in `command line`, can anyone help with how I can fix this?

Comment: run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy for once then check

Answer (score 0):

run this command from CLI.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```